# What are considered as Test Environment apart from windows, Mac , Linux?

Tags: manual-testing

What are considered as Test Environment apart from windows, Mac , Linux?

Chrome, diff Browsers classified as environment?

Answer (score 5):

According to [ISTQB glossary](http://glossary.istqb.org/search/test%20environment), it is:

> An environment containing hardware, instrumentation, simulators, software tools, and other support elements needed to conduct a test.

Answer (score 3):

"Environments" is really too generic a term.
I would consider using the terms:

Operating System of the server.
Usually one of:

- Windows
- OSX
- Linux

Operating System of the Client Computer.
Usually one of:

- Windows
- Max
- Linux

Client Browser
Usually one of:

- Chrome (all OS's)
- Firefox (all OS's)
- Internet Explorer (Windows only)
- Safari (Mac only)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, anything that influences how the software behaves is either an input or part of the test environment.  In a sense, test environment is just a set of inputs that don’t change as often as other inputs.  You might even redefine the line between test environment and inputs depending on the specific test.

Yes, the type of brower could be part of the test environment.  Here are some other examples of properties of a test environment: locale, time zone, network configuration, database type, traffic volume, memory size, and user experience level.

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing on multiple devices then Tablet and mobile models and versions will also come under test environment.

Answer (score 0):

For me test environment is every safe-to-fail environment. Just a mac or a browser is not specific enough - that is where you are using your software.

The real question is - where my software has been installed and running. is it on a server or my pc?